# how to convert decimal values into exponential form in php

Tags: php, floating-point, exponential

I have output like the following float numbers.

```
0.00035074062222222
0.00042088874666667
0.00042088874666667
0.00056118499555556
```

But I want above numbers should be displayed like below,

```
3.51E-05
4.21E-05
4.89E-05
5.61E-05
```

I mean in the form exponential format. I surfed in the net. I could not find any solution for this.

Is it possible in php?. if yes How to do that?.

Comment: The second and third data looks same , How did the output change ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) and the %e and %E scientific notation formatters.

```
echo sprintf('%E', 0.00035074062222222);
```

**Output**

```
3.507406E-4
```

To round up your result use the optional precision specifier.

```
echo sprintf('.2%E', 0.00035074062222222);
```

**Output**

```
3.51E-4
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it any possibilities to make that output as 3.51E-05 (like round up)

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.

Answer (score 1):

See **[sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf)**.

```
$num = 0.00035074062222222;
echo sprintf('%.2E', $num); // .2 used to limit the number of fractional digits.
```

Output:

```
3.51E-4
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.